# I am going nuts trying to figure out how to pass a JSON response to a dynamodb call as a string

Tags: javascript, json

I have tried using `JSON.stringify(customer)`, `customer.toString()`, `String(customer)`, `` `${customer}` ``. Nothing I do gets me the response I need from dynamo. I need to convert the customer variable into something that dynamo can see. my current response is: `{}`. I should see all the table attributes with that key.

```
const {data: {object: {customer}}} = JSON.parse(event.body);

const params = {
        TableName: process.env.table,
        Key: {
                // customerID: 'cus_IO5ntoFCTsjo0x'
                // ^ this works
                customerID: customer
                // ^ this does not
        }
};
const result = await dynamoDb.get(params);
return result;
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(customer) is the one

Comment: I have tried that

Comment: ok ... so, can you show what the variable `customer` actually is - i.e .the output of `console.log(customer)`

Comment: Output is ```"cus_123456"```

Comment: so `customerID: customer` should work ... unless that's an invalid customer id of course